# Launching Browser from ASP.NET Application Requires Administrator?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to launch a web page when my ASP.NET minimal API app launches (the static host URL for my app).

I've tried several methods of doing this.

#### Method 1

In `Program.cs`:

```cs
await app.StartAsync();

string urlToOpen = "http://localhost:" + builder.Configuration.GetSection("HostPort").Value + "/index.html";
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(urlToOpen) { UseShellExecute = true });

await app.WaitForShutdownAsync();
```

This just doesn't work when debugging in VS, or when running the `.exe` after building. However, it DOES work after running the built `.exe` as administrator.

#### Method 2

In `Program.cs`:

```cs
await app.StartAsync();

string urlToOpen = "http://localhost:" + builder.Configuration.GetSection("HostPort").Value + "/index.html";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "/C start" + " " + urlToOpen);

await app.WaitForShutdownAsync();
```

(Opening through cmd instead)

Again, this only works when running the built `.exe` as administrator.

My question is, how do I get this to work without running the built `.exe` as administrator?

Comment: Shouldn't the default `Properties/launchSettings.json` have the `launchBrowser` property set to true? What are you trying to accomplish, shorten the time between hitting the run button in Visual Studio and you (the developer) using the website in your browser?

Comment: @gunr2171 No that only works while I'm developing. I want the browser launch to work once the project has been built.

Comment: Does normal users have access to the route index.html?

Comment: This makes no sense: ASP.Net runs as a service in production. A service shouldn't be lanching user applications. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: @jdweng In terms of file permissions? At least, I thought so. Solved the issue by copying build files to a different directory. See my answer.

Comment: @Charlieface My app isn't exactly going to be used as as a proper server, rather as an alternative to a desktop app that uses a webui. It's just a quick thing I'm throwing together, not a proper polished end product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work, I think the issue was directory permissions or something similar (I kept getting smartscreen warning when running the app in the original build directory). I had my project saved in `C:\Users\User\source\repos`. I copied the built files to a different directory (e.g. Desktop), and the app now opens the browser without needing to be run as administrator (smartscreen warning is also gone, unsure if related).